# why upcast when using arithmetic and access operators

Tags: c++, performance

what would be a reason for upcasting in C++ in the code which will be used for numerical computations over huge amounts of data (a library that I'm using)?

Consider the following hierarchy:

```
template<class T>
class unallocatedArray
{
    public: 
        unallocatedArray(int size, T t)
            : size_(size), t_(0) 
        {

        }

        // Copy constructor. This is the only way to 
        // actually allocate data: if the array is 
        // passed as an argument to the copy constr.
        // together with the size. 

        // Checks. Access operators. Iterators, etc.  
        // Wrappers for stl sorts...

    private:
        int size_;
        T* t_;
};


template<class T>
class myArray 
: public unallocatedArray<T>
{
    public:
        // This type actually allocates the memory.
        myArray (int size)
            : unallocatedArray<T>(size)
        {
            // Check if size < 0..  

            // Allocate.
            this->t_ = new T[size];
        }

        myArray (int size, T t)
        {
            this->t_ = new T[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < this->size_; i ++ )
            {
                this->t_[i] = t;
            }
        }

        // Some additional stuff such as bound checking and error handling. 
        // Append another array (resizing and memory copies), equality 
        // operators, stream operators, etc...

};

template<class T>
class myField
: public myArray<T>
{
    public: 
        // Constructors call the parent ones. No special attributes added. 

        // Maping operations, arithmetical operators, access operator.
};

//

template<class T>
class geomField
: public myField<T>
{
    // myField but mapped on some kind of geometry, like surface meshes, 
    // volume meshes, etc.  
};
```

This is just a very extremely simplified model, just to state that the access operator is defined all the way up, and the arithmetic operators are placed in the myField class. Now, what would be the reason for upcasting geomField to myField, if one needs to perform say 1e07 times the following:

*access the element
perform arithmetical expression*

in the following way:

```
GeomField<myType> geomFieldObject;

myField<myType>&  downCast = geomFieldObject;

// Do the arithmetical operations on the downCast reference.
```

for two of such fields? Isn't upcasting introducing some kind of penalty as well? Are the arithmetic operators not publicly available to the geomField: is this not the whole point of public inheritance?

I didn't design this, it's from an os library that I'm developing in. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the downcast? We're not seeing it. C++ has a lot of cast operators with very different characteristics. We can't tell from this code.

Comment: a) is this just a poor man's `vector`? b) what is this "access operator" you're talking about? c) you mean "upcast", d) nothing is virtual, so there's no runtime dispatch.

Comment: Yes it is a poor man's vector, the lib was developed before STL. b) operator[] would be the access operator - a wrapper for the poor man, c) upcast... sorry.. d) What does this mean? (i'm a mech engineer)

Comment: I'm guessing that the answer is going to be "it doesn't matter". It's probably just a question of convenience, readability or consistency of style. Derived references are implicitly convertible to base references, so you can write whatever you like if you're only interested in base members.

Comment: @tomislav-maric: You have code written before 1994?? I think you might seriously consider the idea of hiring someone to do a rewrite!

Comment: Looks like somebody wanted myField behavior from a GeomField object? If there is no **virtual**, then this is just telling to compiler how to resolve function calls. No overhead there. - But the design seems a bit smelly.

Comment: @Kerrek: the code is HUGE, it deals with simulations in continuum mechanics, there are some STL compliances, but the basic containers are, as you said poor. It's open source, but there's no documentation but the code.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: don't get me wrong: there are other containers as well, and it works with STL, it's efficient, and great in all aspects, but the documentation.

Comment: @visitor: that's right, I found the reason in the code after your comment... put it as an answer so that I can accept it if you wish. :) That's exactly why: the behaviour of the geomField is different than one of myField, but not because of mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess, but some of the arithmetical operations might have been overwritten in `geomField` in order to implement the geometric mapping.

If you have data in an `geomField` but want to perform unmapped operations, that might be a reason for upcasting.

If, on the other hand, none of the operations that are executed on the casted reference are overwritten in `geomField` then you're right that casting is not necessary.

And generally, upcasting doesn't introduce any performance drawbacks because usually (or even in every case, I'm not sure right now ...) it is done completely at compilation time: Consider the following classes:

```
class A {
public:
  void f();
};

class B : public A {
public:
  void f(); // Overwrites A::f
};
```

When you're code looks like

```
B obj;
obj.f();
```

it is translated by the compiler to something like

```
B::f(&obj);
```

and

```
static_cast<A>(obj).f();
```

results in

```
A::f(&obj);
```

i.e. there is no runtime overhead introduced by casting.